# certificate chain not found

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I am signing the jar file. The certificate provided by VeriSign.

It provide 2 certificates: `aplha-primary.cer` and `aplha-secoandary.cer`

I generate the keystore file using the following commands:

```
keytool -importcert -v -alias -primary -keystore keystore/keystore.jks -file aplha-primary.cer
```

and

```
keytool -importcert -v -alias -secoandary -keystore keystore/keystore.jks -file aplha-secoandary.cer
```

It is exported to keystore file.

when I tried to sign the jar file it's giving the exception like

```
  [signjar] jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: must
 reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding
 public key certificate chain.


jarsigner -keystore keystore.jks -storepass **** -keypass ****** Uploader.jar alpha-primary
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: alpha-primary.  alpha-primary must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

Comment: can you provide the command details for how you are signing your jar?

Comment: How did you generate private key?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are missing the private keys. 
For signing of jars is used asymmetrical encryption.
Certificate contains only public key.