# Certificate chain not found, how to fix and publish to Google Play Store?

Tags: android, keytool, jarsigner, jar-signing

**ERROR MESSAGE**:

```
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: project_foo.<br/>
project_foo must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

**QUESTION**:
How do I include a public key certificate chain to address the error?

**BACKGROUND**:
The App Developer has completed an Android app and delivered an unsigned APK called Foo.apk. My objective is to sign and zipalign the APK in preparation for uploading it to the Google Play store. My keystore is located at C:\Path\.keystore on a Windows machine.

**COMMAND LINE**, my command:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore C:\Path\\.keystore Foo.apk project_foo
```

**COMMAND LINE**, response:

```
Enter Passphrase for keystore:
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: project_foo.<br/>
project_foo must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

**ALSO TRIED**:
Verified that I remember the correct password. Using 'keytool -list' from the command line shows me the expected list (it includes one private key).

**PREVIOUS OS QUESTION**: [certificate chain not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259263/certificate-chain-not-found) asked using a `.cer` file from Verisign. I have no similar file available.

**OTHER INFORMATION**: Windows 7 machine, using standard Windows command prompt.

Comment: Are you trying to upload your first app to PlayStore ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is my first app. I uploaded an earlier version of this same product as a Beta to the Play Store. Now we have a Release Candidate version that I want to upload as beta and promote to Production if testing passes.

Comment: Have you generated your own `*.keystore`

Comment: Yes I generated my own. Did I need to start with a public key certificate?

Comment: Instead if signing via command line, try in `Eclispe >> Your Project >> Right Click >> Export >> Android ... >> .. >> Existing >> ...` this will take a min or two.

Comment: I faced this issue when the alias name is not matching with filename. Try using same name for file as well as alias.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

`keytool -keystore formconnect.keystore -list -v`

You can use this command to find out your alias name after you have generated your key.

First line of execution contains the Alias name: `<value>` If keytool is used then alias name might be "mykey".

Use that alias name while packaging the application.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I remember the alias name, as well as I am able to see it from the keytool -list.

Comment: mark to correct answer its resolved my problem too :)

Comment: Worked for me too. For people using this command, you need to mention your `keystore` filename in `formconnect.keystore` in `keytool -keystore formconnect.keystore -list -v`.

Answer (score 16):

i had the same issue 
my commands were

**to generate key**

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore testapp-key.keystore -alias testapp-key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

**and then i did this to sign the app**

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore testapp-key.keystore testapp.apk testapp
```

i got this error

```
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: testapp.<br/>
project_foo must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

then i replaced the alias **'testapp'** in the jarsignir command with the key alias that is **'testapp-key'** it is in first command i.e. key generation command

the command will look like this

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore testapp-key.keystore testapp.apk testapp
```

in your case it will be like this

```
 jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore C:\Path\\.keystore Foo.apk your-key-alias
```

Answer (score 3):

The Developer on our team proposed the solution that fixed the problem. Previously I had copied the Foo.apk into the directory with the jarsigner.exe and tried to run it there. He proposed:

1. Set the PATH environment variable so Windows can find the jarsigner executable.
2. Move the Foo.apk to the path where the keystore was located.
3. Run the command below (without using a path to find the keystore).

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore .keystore Foo.apk project_foo
```

It works! Removing the necessity to specify file path for the keystore fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, this worked for a Linux signing operation as well, step 2, move everything into the same directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

add release unsigned.apk folder path

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore keystorename.keystore .....**\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk** aliasname

it's work for me !!

Comment: so we can upload the generated file to playstore?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sign your .aab or .apk ,from Android Studio but keep getting this error even though you are doing everything right, here is the solution that worked for me: 
Go to search and find Command Prompt. Run it as Administrator. Now Type this line.

```
"C:--->Your Path To jarsiner<---\jdk1.8.0_192\bin\jarsigner" -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "C: **--->Your Path To the Keystore<---**\Desktop\OfficalBuilds\MyKey.keystore" "C:**--->Your Path To the .apk Or .aab<---**\Desktop\MyFinalBuild.aab"  "My Alias "
```

If you tried the above solutions,you will notice now the alias is typed inside " ". Also sometime there is a space at the end "My Alias "