# Error while signing an kivy app for the android store

Tags: android, python, kivy

I tried to sign my application, which is called `LieDedector-1.2.0-release-unsigned.apk` and programmed in kivy, for the android store with `jarsigner`.
Both the apk and my keystore, called `My1Key.keystore`, are in the `keystores` directory.
So I tried to sign my app with to following command:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ./keystores/My1Key.keystore ./keystores/LieDedector-1.2.0-release-unsigned.apk cb-play
```

And I got the error message:

> jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: cb-play.  cb-play must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

Why can't I sign my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that would be is related to the naming of your keystore. Our command is almost identical and works. It's the last item, cb-play, where (I think) it goes wrong....

[Certificate chain not found, how to fix and publish to Google Play Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750259/certificate-chain-not-found-how-to-fix-and-publish-to-google-play-store)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, I did it!
I did it like this:

1. I generated an release apk with

   buildozer android release

2.Than I created a keystore

3. Than I found out my alias name with: `keytool -keystore My1Key.keystore -list -v`

The output should look like this:

```
Keystore-Typ: JKS
Keystore-Provider: SUN

Keystore enthält 1 Eintrag

Aliasname: m1k
Erstellungsdatum: 31.07.2015
Eintragstyp: PrivateKeyEntry
Zertifikatskettenlänge: 1
Zertifikat[1]:
```

In my case, the aliasname was m1k

4. Than I generated signt my apk file with:

`jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ./keystores/My1Key.keystore ./keystores/LieDedector-1.2.0-release-unsigned.apk m1k`

(I had both my apk and my keystore in the `keystores` direktory, my apk was called `LieDedector-1.2.0-release-unsigned.apk` my keystore `My1Key.keystore` and the aliasname was `m1k`)

I hope this helps someone :)