# how to sign a already compiled apk?

Tags: android, eclipse, algorithm, android-studio, apktool

hi its my first android project, i build my unsinged apk, i have no prior experience with certificates, follow tutorials from [android developer page](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) for signing my app, create a keystore using cmd `keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\users\anita\my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

tried to signed app `jarsigner -verbose -keystore my-release-key.keystore flying_birda.apk alias_name`

jarsigner: certificate chain not found for (my alias_name). alias_name must reference a valid keystore key a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

i see a same problem 
[Certificate chain not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750259/certificate-chain-not-found-how-to-fix-and-publish-to-google-play-store)

is it a problem that my keystore have only a public key? if yes

then anyone can help me ho to make a complete key entry with a private key.

i am working it from last 2 days

but did not solve my problem. 
 how can I sign it properly outside eclipse or android studio?
any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: any particular reason why you don't want to sign it in android studio using your key store?

Comment: Try checking this link, might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use haibision apk signer [from github](https://github.com/haibison/apk-signer)