# Certificate chain not found for: <alias>. Can I recover it?

Tags: android, apk, keystore, jarsigner

I'm developing a Cordova app for IOS and Android,

After a year, I made some changes and I want to update the app.

The problem begins when I need to sign the android's .apk,

I lost my `.keystore`, found it and included in the project dir ( different computer )

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore android-release-unsigned.keystore platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk appName
```

This returns:

> jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: appName.  appName must
>   reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and
>   corresponding public key certificate chain.

what causes might be? it's not the right .keystore or the right alias? I'm missing some other file? (Can I restore from the original computer, somehow?)

I'm trying to prevent to have to submit a different app...

Comment: Seems you are using an invalid alias. List the keystore content to see what is its name: `keytool -keystore android-release-unsigned.keystore -list -v` or open it with GUI tool KeystoreExplorer

Comment: Fuah! @pedrofb, me has salvado! Please write an answer with it

Comment: Encantado de ayudar!. Happy to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you are using an invalid alias and jarsigner can not find it.  List the keystore content to see what is the correct name:

```
keytool -keystore android-release-unsigned.keystore -list -v
```

You can use also the GUI tool KeystoreExplorer to view the content.

You can also check [Certificate chain not found, how to fix and publish to Google Play Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750259/certificate-chain-not-found-how-to-fix-and-publish-to-google-play-store)