# Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'. Can't build app bundle

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-app-signing

I get the title and the text below when I try and fail to build an .aab file using flutter build appbundle:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsignerfailed with exit code 1 :
> jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: keystore.  keystore must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

I had to reset my signing key. The google developer support had me generate a new .jks file with the following command line which I ran from within my project folder:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
```

He then instructed me to convert this file into a .pem file using this command:

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

I then emailed him the upload_certificate.pem file. I immediately noticed that the keystore.jks file was red in the sidebar and I get this upon clicking on it:

"The file 'keystore.jks' is not associated with any file type. Please define the association:"

The .pem file is also red, but clicking on it shows the text that makes up the key.

Do I need to reset the signing key again and do something different? Is there a way to fix the issue causing this error?

Comment: It looks like there is a problem in your flutter config. Could you share what your signing config looks?

Comment: Also, googling the error message returned this as first link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750259/certificate-chain-not-found-how-to-fix-and-publish-to-google-play-store

Comment: I saw that link. When i tried the recommend command line, I get this error: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: formconnect.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: formconnect.keystore

Comment: Do you mean what's in my key.properties file?

Comment: Here's what's in my key.properties file: storePassword=Test*** keyPassword=Test*** keyAlias=keystore storeFile=/Users/****/Desktop/***/matto_flutter/keystore.jks

Comment: When I try this command jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\matto_flutter.keystore matto_flutter.apk keystore               I get this response: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports jarsigner.

Comment: When you run the command, you have to replace `formconnect.keystore` with the path to YOUR keystore file, i.e. `keystore.jks`. That will give list you the aliases of the keys in your keystore.

Answer (score 1):

As dumb as this may sound, I spent 24 hours on this and all I had to was enter `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

You have `keyAlias=keystore` in your key.properties while it looks like the alias you created is named `upload` (see in your `keytool export` command).

Repleace with `keyAlias=upload` and that should work if your password is correct.

Comment: When I replace keyAlias to equaling upload, the error changes to: Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.                
> Keystore file '/Users/****/Desktop/****/matto_flutter/android/app/upload.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I replace the keyAlias with upload, which is the keyAlias, if I change the storeFile to end in /alias.jks I get this error instead: Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.                
> Keystore file '/Users/****/Desktop/****/matto_flutter/android/app/upload.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.
 If I leave the keystore file ending in keystore.jks I get the same error as before.

Comment: Does the file  '/Users/****/Desktop/****/matto_flutter/android/app/upload.jks'  actually exist? It looks like you're just pointing to a keystore file that doesn't exist.

Comment: The commands you shared show that the upload keystore you created was named 'keystore.jks' so that's the one you need to reference.

Comment: When I use the correct Alias and path ending in keystore, I continue to get the error that is the title of this post.

Comment: What do you mean by "the correct alias"? Do you mean "upload"? Did you use the command from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750259/certificate-chain-not-found-how-to-fix-and-publish-to-google-play-store to check what were the available aliases in the keystore file you're using?